# What's the best way to go about finding jobs that offer homeworking?

Tags: job-search, work-life-balance

I'm a software developer in the UK, and I've found that it's very rare (maybe 5% of the time) to find an employer that will even consider *any* working from home, let alone for the majority of the time. I see it as a win-win; you're able to work in the home environment you are most productive in, and you can use the time you would've been commuting to/from work a bit longer for the employer. Not only that, but you're not adding to road congestion either. Skype, etc. make communication with coworkers a snap these days.

So what's the best way to go about finding homeworking jobs? Is it better to demand it from the get-go (and therefore have it written into the initial contract), or wait a few months and then ask for it? Is it perhaps just a cultural thing whereby homeworking is more common in the US than in the UK?

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Generally this is called working remotely, or remote working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One place to start would be monster.com, indeed.com or careerbuilder.com and search for companies which allow telecommuting and what we refer to here in the US as 1099 which are basically freelance independent contractors. Coming from the Silicon Valley in California, there are quite a few companies willing to offer the flexibility for telecommuting or homeworking as you called it. Akton is right about the unique skills or at least solid experience (minimum of a mid-level developer typically). I'm not so sure about UK based companies, but usually the best way to get your foot in the door towards telecommuting is to network with the recruiters for those companies and check LinkedIn. LinkedIn is a great source for tech related jobs and connections that can get you the remote work you're wanting.

Recruiters often know the companies which frequently employ remote developers because those companies already understand the benefit and cost savings of telecommuting over physical commuting.

Comment: @Jez take look at this: https://remote4me.com/

The site is full of 100% remote jobs. To see jobs in Europe select the European timezone. (By the way, I'm the author)

Answer (score 3):

> So what's the best way to go about finding homeworking jobs?

**Identify companies that allow homeworking and apply to them directly.** They may not have a suitable position at the moment but, if they have you on file, you may be among the first they call. Make sure to identify any skill gaps and fill them so, when they do call you, you will be ready.

In terms of organizations, from my own experience, homeworking tends to be less accepted in larger, older organizations and more accepted in smaller, newer organizations. Software development, though, is ideally suited to home working.

**Make your preference for homeworking known to any recruiters.** This may shut off large sections of the industry but, when a position becomes available, you may be top of mind.

Some job websites also have homeworking options, such as careers.stackoverflow.com as @LegoStormtroopr mentioned.

> Is it better to demand it from the get-go (and therefore have it written into the initial contract), or wait a few months and then ask for it?

Most jobs that I have been in require a short probation period, even if it is to learn the ropes and meet the people. Being able to spend some time in the office, even if it is only a day a week or so, is also helpful. You appear to be part of the team and can spend a bit of time socializing.

Some companies may see working from home as a benefit or expect a reduced productivity. You also may need to accept a small pay cut.

To help get homeworking, ensure you have a unique and strong set of skills. Being valuable means companies are more likely to compromise to get you.

Make sure you have good time management and written communication skills. Talking about how you handle being managed remotely in an interview can help greatly. For example, using automated code review tools can be much more effective than doing a code review over the phone. Pair programming works best if you can use screen sharing and voice chat software.